# Big-$O$ inside a log operation

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

I would appreciate help in understanding how:

$$\log \left(\frac{1}{s - 1} - O(1)\right) = \log \left(\frac{1}{s - 1}\right) + O(1)\text{ as }s \rightarrow 1^+$$

I thought of perhaps a Taylor series for $\log(x - 1)$, but that would have an $O(x^2)$ term.

Also I would appreciate any reference or tutorial recommendations to get a good understanding of big-$O$ notation in general.

Thanks very much.

Comment: $\log(1/(s-1)+C)-\log(1/(s-1))=\log(1+(s-1)C)<D$ for some constants  $C$ and $D$. (as $s\rightarrow 1^{+}$).

Comment: I think the wikipedia article is not bad to start learning about it. It has lots of examples. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: @Franklin.vp: your comment can probably become an answer.

Comment: @Andrew : You seem to think that "log" should be _outside_ of the math tags.  But this is just the sort of thing that TeX, and later LaTeX, were designed for!  If you type a\log b, with a backslash, then you see $a\log b$, with $\log$ not italicized and with proper spacing.  (I fixed this in your question.)

Comment: @MichaelHardy I don't think it should be outside, I just format ad hoc, picking up what I can and doing the best I can. You inferred correctly that I did not like the italics. But other than the diss, thanks for letting me know and fixing it.

Comment: @Franklin.vp Dear Franklin, as Willie Wong suggested, if you want to write it as an answer, I will accept it. Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(s)=O(1)$ as $s\rightarrow1^+$ means that there is a constant $C$ such that $|f(s)|<C$ for $s$ close to $1^+$.

One thing to always keep in mind is that equalities between things with $O$'s or $o$'s are not really symmetric equalities. This means that it is probably safe to prove this 'in both directions'.

The left hand side is talking about a function $f(s)$ such that there is a constant $C$ such that $|e^{f(s)}-\frac{1}{s-1}|<C$ for $s$ close to $1^+$.

The right hand side is talking about a function $g(s)$ such that there is a constant $D$ such that $|g(s)-\log(\frac{1}{s-1})|<D$.

Let us check that the function on the left $f$ satisfies the description on the right. According to its description, we can write $f(s)$ as $\log(\frac{1}{s-1}+h(s))$, where $h$ is bounded as $s\rightarrow 1^+$. We subtract $\log(\frac{1}{s-1})$ and get $\log(1+(s-1)h(s))$. Since $h$ is bounded and $(s-1)\rightarrow 0$ then this subtraction is bounded. This was the description on the right.

Now, we do the other direction. Let us check that $g$ satisfies the description on the left. From what we know of $g$ we can write it as $\log(\frac{1}{s-1})+a(s)$ with $a$ bounded. We now compute $e^{\log(1/(s-1))+a(s)}-\frac{1}{s-1}=\frac{e^{a(s)}}{(s-1)}-\frac{1}{(s-1)}=\frac{e^{a(s)}-1}{(s-1)}$ ... oops.

I guess that is why this is not really a symmetric equality.

So, reading from left to right the equality is true. Reading from right to left, it is not.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to fully articulate the asymmetry. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}\log\left(\frac{1}{s-1}+\mathcal O(1)\right)&=\log\left(\frac{1}{s-1}\left(1+\mathcal O(s-1)\right)\right)=\log\left(\frac{1}{s-1}\right)+\log\left(1+\mathcal O(s-1)\right)\\ \notag &=\log\left(\frac{1}{s-1}\right)+\mathcal O(s-1) \\ \notag &=\log\left(\frac{1}{s-1}\right)+\mathcal O(1)\end{align}$$

the third equality holding since $$\log(1+x)=\mathcal O(x),\quad x\to0.$$

Some relevant notes here (http://www.ma.hw.ac.uk/~simonm/ae.pdf).