# Can You Perform Operations on a Big O Term

Tags: asymptotics, gamma-function

I am a student and have been reading about Stirling's approximation of the gamma function. Wikipedia has a result as follows

$$\Gamma(z) = \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{z}}\left(\frac{z}{e}\right)^z\left(1 + O\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\right)$$

If I take the log of both sides I get
$$\ln\left(\Gamma(z)\right) = \ln\left(\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{z}}\left(\frac{z}{e}\right)^z\left(1 + O\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\right)\right) = \frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{2\pi}{z}\right) + z\ln(z) - z + \ln\left(1 + O\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\right)$$

I would like to know if there is a way to convert the $\ln\left(1 + O\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\right)$ term to a single $O(f(z))$ term. Or maybe similarly, what happens if you take the natural log of a big O term?

I have also looked at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429216/big-o-inside-a-log-operation?rq=1). One thing I noticed in this post is that the asymptotic notation included information about where it converges. In the above post, the user who asked the question specifies as $s \rightarrow 1^+$. In this case, I believe I would be looking at $z \rightarrow \infty$. If that is the case why doesn't the $O\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$ term go away since $$\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{z} = 0$$

After some help from @Andrew D. Hwang, @FShrike, and @CyclotomicField, I understand now that $\ln(1 + u) = u - \frac{u^2}{2} + \frac{u^3}{3} - \ldots$ by the Maclaurin expansion. I also believe that we can similarly say
$$\ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{z}\right) = \frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{2z^2} + \frac{1}{3z^3} \ldots = O\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) | z\to\infty$$.

So, now I am not entirely sure if
$$\ln\left(1 + O\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\right) = O\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$$
However, I believe this is saying that there is some constant $c$ such that
$$\ln\left(1 + \frac{c}{z}\right) = O\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$$
I believe any positive $c$ would work here. Am I right in thinking this?

I appreciate any direction you can provide.

Comment: Since $\ln(1 + u) = u + O(u^2) = O(u)$ for $u \approx 0$, we have $\ln(1 + \frac{1}{z}) = O(\frac{1}{z})$ as $z \to \infty$; is that what you're asking?

Comment: That sounds like it is helpful. Could you explain how you have $\ln\left(1 + u\right) = u + O\left(u^2\right) = O(u)$?

Comment: Do you know the Maclaurin series of $\ln(1+u)=u-u^2/2+u^3/3-\cdots$ for $|u|\lt1$? That’s where it comes from

Comment: Thank you @Fshrike. I am not very familiar with that. I am still a bit confused though as I would think the higher order terms would dominate. Why can we say it is $u + O(u^2)$ when there is a $u^3$ term there?

Comment: When dealing with asymptotic notation it is very important to know what the implicit “... as $u\to?$” is. Here, as $u\to0$, $u$ is “significantly” larger than $u^2,u^3,...$ but you’re right, it would be the other way round if we were dealing with $u\to\infty$

Comment: @Fshrike Thank you that makes complete sense. I will update my original question to clarify now that I understand this a little bit more.

Comment: I would just add when working with inequalities as you do with, landau notation, you're often able to make substitutions of all kinds that would normally not be true. For example $\sin (x) \leq x$ is true for positive $x$ even though $\sin (x) \neq x$. This opens up a lot of manipulations that you wouldn't see in other contexts.